# Dynamic-linked DLL needs to share a global variable with its caller

Tags: c++, global-variables, dynamic-linking

I have a static library *libStatic* that defines a global variable like this

Header file `libStatic/globals.h`:

```
extern int globvar;
```

Code file `libStatic/globals.cpp`:

```
int globvar = 42;
```

The DLL *libDynamic* and the executable *runner* are using this global variable. Furtheron, `libDynamic` is linked at run-time into *runner* (via `LoadLibrary()`, `GetProcAddress()`, and the works...)

I understand this will lead to `globvar` being created twice, once in the heap of *runner* and once in the heap of *libDynamic*, which is of course very undesirable.

Is there a good away around this? How can I ensure that *libDynamic* and *runner* are using the same `globvar`?

Comment: Do you have to use a global variable?  Perhaps you can think of a better means to pass around such state?

Comment: The example is simplified a lot to not overcomplicate the question. In reality, its not just a simple int variable but a complex singleton object. I am looking for a way to ensure the singleton exists only once in the combined scope of application and dynamic library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to let the `.DLL` point to the global variable of the executable. Right after loading you would call a special function inside that library (something like `SetGlobVar(int*)`). That way the library will always point to the same global variable as the `.EXE`.

Comment: I was afraid I would get this answer... Though it is 100 percent correct I don't like this neccessity and would prefer a more elegant way if it exists.

Comment: Move the global variable into a separate module (dll) that can be dynamically linked by both (NOT runtime linked! dynamically linked). Use the [nifty counter pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) for the global variable. It might be an overkill for your need, but this is how the basic_iostream library creates cout and its friends.